# Trouble with simple multiplication

Tags: python, math

I am trying to find all curzon numbers as a simple practice. I keep getting an error:

```
ERROR:   File "<string>", line 10
if(2 *num+1) % (i*i += 1) == 0:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Right now my code is :

```
def is_curzon(num):
i = num
if(2*num+1) % (i*i += 1) == 0:
    return true
```

Comment: This is not valid `i*i += 1` your trying to do an inplace modification of something that doesnt exist. what is this ment to be?

Comment: Did you mean `i * i + 1`?

Comment: When I tried it, the `^` pointed to the `+=`, not `1`. Please make sure you copy the error message exactly.

Comment: Also your function indentation is wrong. That must be another copying error.

Comment: You have a lot of indentation problems. Suggestion: [edit] your question by copy-and pasting the actual code and error as-is, and using triple-backticks (`\`\`\``) to do the formatting.

Comment: Why is it not valid? (what is an inplace modification?) I am somewhat new to programing btw

Comment: Inplace operators are `...=` . In your place `+=`. If you don't know what is is/does, why did you use it?

Comment: Thats a fair point. I think from now on I will try better to fully understand what I code actually means instead of just changing stuff till it works. Thank you for the help and thank you for helping me realize what I can get better at (I hope this does not come off passive agressive, I am being genuine)

Answer (score 1):

[Inplace modification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)
Simple example on how get started with the Addition assignment `(+=)`

The quick solution for your problem would be:

```
def is_curzon(num):
i = num
if(2*num+1) % (i*i + 1) == 0:
    return true
```

**Inplace modification** is used to modify the value of a variable based on the **previous value** and store it in the same variable.

`a += 1` is the equivalent of `a = a + 1`
It doesn't comprehend where to store the new value when using `i*i += ...`.